# How much time passes during Daredevil?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil, daredevil-2015

Considering only the main, present-day events of the first season of *Daredevil*, how much time passes from the beginning of episode one through the end of episode thirteen?

Comment: You can calculate it pretty well through bruise fading in his face

Answer (score 5):

I've been wondering this as well, but have been unable to find an official answer anywhere. I've come to a conclusion based on guesswork, but obviously it involves speculation:

**From the first time Daredevil dons his black suit on-screen to the debut of the red suit, it appears that approximately one month of time passes in-universe.**

Now, here's my reasoning. The first several episodes appear to be happening back-to-back, with each episode connecting almost seamlessly, with only a few hours or less passing between episodes. There are a couple of cases where he gets injured pretty badly, and afterwards disappears for a day or two - likely spending the time resting and meditating to

> accelerate his healing process, as mentioned by Stick.

By Episode 9 "Speak of the Devil", we can assume that roughly two weeks has passed so far, when Daredevil is

> severely injured - almost killed - during his fight with Nobu.

After this event, he disappears into seclusion for several days, possibly a week or more. Following that, we have to allow for several hours, or even days, in order that

> Melvin can design and create the red suit.

Therefore, with a minimum of healing time in-between bouts, we're looking at least a month from start to finish, obviously not including any of the time shown in flashbacks.

**UPDATE:** I went back to the first & last episodes and tried to get dates off of the newspaper articles ("Union Allied Scandal" in pilot & "Daredevil Collars Fisk" in finale), but the dates on the newspaper are illegible, even in the closeups. Perhaps someone with a higher def screen or viewer can provide those.

Comment: One thing to consider: shortly after we first meet Ben Urich, he talks to the hospital administrator, who says she's giving him/his wife a five day extension. in episode 10, they mention the extension running out, and he needs to find a new place for the wife.

Comment: @phantom42 you're right, and I did think of that. Given the physical punishment Daredevil takes, though, it seems impossible that he did it all in a week, or even two weeks. Even considering the healing, a month is pushing what's possible. All I could figure is that the nurse friend actually gave Ben longer than the 5 days they discussed, but couldn't push it any further than 2 weeks or so.

Comment: I'm looking at the paper in the last episode and interestingly, it doesn't have a date anywhere on the front page. It has a weather forecast and a page number for more weather info, and a note to visit their website.

Comment: In either episode 10 or 11 I thought I heard Foggy make some offhand comment about "we've been working on this for months" which caught me off guard because the show had been so slow-paced before. So it's possible they abruptly jumped forward a large amount of time without really telling the audience. This was when Daredevil was taking his break after fighting Nobu (I don't remember exactly when it was, I just watched the last 9 episodes in a row)

Comment: @childcat15 good catch if accurate! I'll be home in about 3 hours - I'll watch the episode again and see if I can get the dialogue you're referring to.